# JavaScript's bind() with currying. How does these code work?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

These code was posted on CodeReview two days ago:

```
function curry(f, self) {
  return function () {
    if (arguments.length == f.length) {
      return f.apply(self, arguments);
    }
    arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return curry(f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat(arguments)));
  }
}

function f(a, b, c, d) {
  return this + a + b + c + d;
}

document.write("f(1, 2, 3, 4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1, 2, 3, 4), "<br>");
document.write("f(1, 2, 3)(4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1, 2, 3)(4), "<br>");
document.write("f(1)(2, 3, 4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1)(2, 3, 4), "<br>");
document.write("f(1)(2)(3)(4) = ", curry(f, 0)(1)(2)(3)(4), "<br>");
```

What I'm not able to understand is:

There is made a new copy of f by using bind(). The parameter already provided are assigned to the copy but what is with the variable "self"?

I've tried to "sketch" what I mean:

```
// Second parenthesis (marked with =>): There are three of four  
// expected parameter provided: 
document.write("f(1, 2, 3)(4) = ", curry(f, 0) => (1, 2, 3) <= (4), "<br>");

// Makes an array-literal with "self" (== 0) as only element in it.
// Then adds the parameter already provided to these array by
// using concat(). => Results in an array [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ].
// Then makes a new copy of f with these values bind to it as parameter. 
// These new instance of the function is then passed to the curry-function.
return curry(f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat(arguments)));
```

The copy of f should have it's four parameter. It should be executed and resulting "return 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3;" and return 6.

Why isn't that the case?

Perhaps someone can answer that. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Where does that second `0` come from, and why do you think it's evaluated (to `6`) already when there are only 3 out of 4 parameters only?

Comment: Calls the curry-function and gives 0 as 2nd parameter (parameter "self"). Then later concats self (=== 0) together with the parameter of the second call (which I have marked with => <=). In the body of f the 0 is used to overwrite the value of the this-keyword. So therefore: this-keyword (== 0) + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3. The 0 has been used to overwrite the this-keyword AND it has been added to the array given to the function. Therefore I think it's two times in there.

Comment: whatever is going on, that's gotta be one of the ugliest implementations of curry I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is with the variable "self"? It is used to overwrite the this-keyword AND it has been added to the array given to the function.

No, it's not:

```
  f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat(arguments))
≡ f.bind.apply(f, [self].concat([1, 2, 3]))
≡ f.bind.apply(f, [0, 1, 2, 3])
≡ f.bind(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

`self`/`0` is bound as the `this` argument, `1`, `2` and `3` are bound as three partially applied parameters. Nothing is duplicated here. The result is a function

```
function bound_f(x, ...args)
    return f.call(0, 1, 2, 3, x, ...args);
}
```

that is then again curried and can be invoked with `4` as the argument.

Comment: @Bergi Good explanation indeed. Thanks a lot.